# dynamically creating radio button with php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a php mysql script which saves the attendance of some class. when i select class name from drop down list it shows the list of student and in front of each student there should be three radio button for Present, on leave and absent. and at the last of the student list a Save Attendance button. any one please help me.

Comment: Show me the mysql query and the html code for single student.

Comment: @abdul please share html code

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML in PHP too. if your logic is clear to make this list 
you can add radio button where ever you want in your PHP script too.